# What is a hypernova and have we observed any?

Tags: star, supernova

Inspired by the question ["What does it mean for a star to go nova or supernova? Can I safely observe these?"](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/271/what-does-it-mean-for-a-star-to-go-nova-or-supernova-can-i-safely-observe-these), I am curious about what **hypernovas** are?

Have we observed any occurring, or the at least the after-effects?

Is there an upper limit of how large a stellar explosion can be?

[image: hypernova]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hypernova is just a really, really big supernova.  [UMass has a (tacky designed) web page that explains it](http://www.astro.umass.edu/~wqd/hnr/faq.htm).

> A hypernova explosion typically has a mechanical energy output of ~ 10^53 ergs, or about a factor of 100 greater than a supernova.

Regarding aftereffect, the page says this:

> The age of the hypernova remnant NGC5471B is about 30 thousand years, while the age of MF83 is about 1 million years.

As best as I am able to determine, we have not had a chance to observe any hypernova candidates in the modern era, although [APOD featured the same one as mentioned by UMass](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/apod/ap990420.html):

[image: APOD Picture of Hypernoava remnant NGC5471B]

[According to New Scientist, research *suggest* the upper limit to a star is about 150 solar masses](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn7115-mysterious-limit-on-star-size-revealed.html#.UkTuToash8E). These are the stars that create the infamous supernovas.his is as derived from the [Eddington Limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_limit).  Although [R136a1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R136a1) is an example of a star at nearly double that.  It is believed that these monsters are what are responsible for hypernovas. There is much to be learned from these stellar monsters!

Comment: Gamma Ray Burst *may* be caused by hypernovae. So if this is the case, we have few hundreds observations.